# How to retrieve selected nodes in VirtualStringTree after selection changed?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I have VST with MultiSelect option enabled. How can I retrieve the list of selected nodes in VirtualStringTree when the selection changes via keyboard events?

I tried using the below code in the OnFocusChanged event

```
procedure TForm1.UpdateSelection(VST: TVirtualStringTree);
Var
  NodeArray: TNodeArray;
  NodeData: PNodeData;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Memo1.Clear;

  NodeArray := VST.GetSortedSelection(False);
  For I := Low(NodeArray) to High(NodeArray) do
  Begin
    NodeData := VST.GetNodeData(NodeArray[I]);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(NodeData.Caption);
  End;
end;

procedure TForm1.VST1FocusChanged(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode;
    Column: TColumnIndex);
begin
  UpdateSelection(VST1);
end;
```

This works fine if I use the mouse and shift key, however, if I use the keyboard, i.e select node, then press shift and then down arrow to select multiple nodes, the selection returns the full list - 1.

This seems like a bug? Any ideas on how to get the full selection when using the keyboard?

Comment: It would be good if you include the used Delphi and VST version in your question.

Comment: I found the same problem to occur in Delphi 7 VT v5, and Berlin 1.0 VT v6

Comment: Focused node and selected nodes are something different,if you need the selection (especially in case of multi-select), do not use focus events, but selection event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can also reproduce this behavior (D5, VT ver 4.5.5). looks like a bug to me, and I'll explain why:

Seems like the keyboard event(s) calls `FocusChanged` but does not change the internal `FSelectedCount` at the moment `FocusChanged` event is triggered. if you look at the code of `GetSortedSelection`, the first line is `SetLength(Result, FSelectionCount);` and if you test `VST1.SelectionCount` property it is set to the actual selection count - 1 (as you describe) or if you press SHIFT-END the *previous* value remains.

I have never noticed this in my own app because I use a delayed action via `PostMessage` in this specific event. this results the correct internals when the event handler exits. this could be one solution.

However, the proper solution which I believe is the correct way, is to handle the selection in the `OnChange` event handler - the selection could be change regardless of a focus node change.

Comment: Thanks. I also came across [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995559/virtualtreeview-properly-handling-selection-changes?rq=1) which mentions the `OnChange` event handler, and to set the `ChangeDelay` property. Can you show how you use `PostMessage`?

Comment: Welcome. You can look into `TForm.Release` for example and see how its implemented to get the general idea of how to use `PostMessage`.

Answer (score 1):

There are `OnAddToSelection` and `OnRemoveFromSelection` events which are meant to track changes in selection, I quess you should use these instead of `OnFocusChanged` event.

Did a quick test and it seems that when `OnAddToSelection` fires the `GetSortedSelection` method returns the array of nodes already selected and the node to be selected (or added to the selection) as `Node` argument.

When `OnRemoveFromSelection` fires the `GetSortedSelection` method returns the array of selected nodes and `Node` parameter is the node about to be removed from the selection. So you could say that the events are not competely "symmetrical".

When `GetSortedSelection` method is used in `OnRemoveFromSelection` the app indeed AVs on exit. I would say this is a bug in VT. Seting `VT.OnRemoveFromSelection := nil;` in form's `OnDestroy` handler seems to fix it... as you seem to have your solution I didn't investigate any further.

Comment: nice to know about OnAddToSelection and OnRemoveFromSelection. no such event handlers in older versions. +1

Comment: Not sure when they were introduced, I have them on VT 5.0

Comment: I would not +1 this, since I tried it and it does not solve the problem (it is actually worse), and I get an AV when I close the app. So please give more details if this actually is a solution...

Comment: I did some of my own testing and encountered another bug: If using these events, an AV occurs just as I select all nodes with the keyboard (shift and arrow key). So it seems like it could be a possible solution, but is laden with bugs. Perhaps because people have not used it... (I tested on V5)